# What does using a dollar sign after $this-> in PHP mean?

Tags: php, syntax, oop

I'm a little confused by some PHP syntax I've come across.  Here is an example:

```
$k = $this->_tbl_key;

if( $this->$k)
{
   $ret = $this->_db->updateObject( $this->_tbl, $this, $this->_tbl_key, $updateNulls );
}
else
{
    $ret = $this->_db->insertObject( $this->_tbl, $this, $this->_tbl_key );
}
```

My question is basically what does `$this->$k` mean?  I figured it might mean the member variable that goes by the name of whatever is in `$this->_tbl_key`, but how would that work?  Is it possible to add member variables to a class at run-time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It'll look up whatever the value of "k" is, and treat it as a variable name. These two samples are the same:

```
echo ($obj->myvar);

####

$k = "myvar";
echo ($obj->$k);
```

Comment: OK, that's what I thought to begin with - I need to find where that variable is coming from, then.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that is a case of [variable variables](http://us.php.net/language.variables.variable).

Comment: It's very much not, though. John Millikin's answer is correct.

Comment: John's answer is more complete but Paolo is correct. This is a variably named variable. If you want to think more specifically in terms of the OOP usage you could also call it a variable property (which is described in Paolo's link).